# Create composer-rest-api server

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm studying `hyperledger composer` and want to make a simple server and mobile app to interact with it in my local home-network. I have a linux server with `docker` and without access to the internet. I deploy my network to server and have cards on my computer. Now i want to start rest-api on server.

If you start `composer-rest-server` on server, it needs cards that i have on my computer. So, i can't start `composer-rest-server` here. With the `docker container hyperledger/composer-rest-server` the same problem, it needs cards.

Well, the only solution is to export cards to server? Can i do it without installing `composer-cli` on server? Maybe there are other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The composer rest server necessarily needs a business network card in order to generate the REST API. You should import the card into your server.
For more informations see: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server